# print out xquery sequence and exit

Tags: xquery, sequence, pretty-print, marklogic

Is there a way to "die" in execution flow in an xquery file and output a nicely formatted printout of a sequence variable?

I'm trying something like:

```
return { fn:error(xs:QName("ERROR"), $xml) }
```

but that doesn't quite seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate in functional terms on what you are trying to achieve? throwing an error might not be the best solution here.

Comment: just trying to get some printouts for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment (you need it for debugging) I guess you are looking for the `fn:trace` function, described here http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_trace.html

If you want to abort the execution flow and output an error in your application you should in fact use the XQuery exception handling.

Comment: Is there any way to print out a nicely formatted sequence, instead of it shoving all the values into one long string?

Comment: Why do you need nicely formatted stuff if it is just for debugging purpose?

Comment: As they output is going to ````stderr```` you could grab it there and format it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, omitting the `return` if this isn't part of a FLWOR expression.

```
...
return fn:error((), "DEBUG", $xml)
```

There's no need for curly braces unless you're enclosing an expression, for example `<x>{ current-time() }</x>`. The return expression is not enclosed.

With MarkLogic it's best to leave the first parameter of `fn:error` empty. That way you don't have to worry about a QName, and anyway some folks believe that it's reserved for predefined errors. MarkLogic uses the second parameter to fill in `error:code`, and the third parameter for data.

For more on `fn:error`, see http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:error and https://github.com/robwhitby/xray/pull/11

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you could put that into a FLWOR expression as needed. The `return` is not valid outside a FLWOR or a typeswitch. So if the context isn't a FLWOR, omit the `return`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWOR has more.